# Make function payable for a specific ERC20 token?

Tags: erc-20, payable

When a method is `payable`, it's possible to send ether to the contract while calling it, and the function can check the amount sent through `msg.value`.

How can I make a function receive something other than ether, such as an ERC20 token?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An ERC20 token is just another contract. The ERC20 standard gives you two functions that work together to help pay a contract: `approve()` and `transferFrom()`.

If the token contract is called "token" and the contract you're trying to pay is called "store", the process looks like this:

1. The user calls `token.approve(store, amount);` This gives `store` permission to transfer `amount` of the user's tokens.
2. The user calls `store.buy();`, which calls `token.transferFrom()` to perform the actual transfer.

The `buy()` function might look like this:

```
function buy() external {
    require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, this, amount));
    // having now received <amount> tokens from the sender, deliver whatever was
    // purchased, etc.
}
```

Comment: Your `buy()` function needs a parameter `uint256 amount`.

Comment: is it `address(this)` instead of `this`?