# Mint NFT on Polygon using WETH instead of MATIC

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js

I have a ERC721 smart contract deployed on polygon test network mumbai.

I'm calling the `mint` function directly on my website, using `ethers.js`, to create a NFT:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
const signer = await provider.getSigner();
const accountSigner = await signer.getAddress();
const contractInstanceWrite = new ethers.Contract(myContractAddress, abi, signer);
mint = await contractInstanceWrite.mint(accountSigner, 1, { gasPrice: gas_price, gasLimit: gas_limit, value: cost });
```

It prompts MetaMask to pay the `cost` with MATIC, but I want to prompt it to directly pay with WETH (As I know, the fees must be paid with MATIC but the cost of the NFT can be with another token).

How to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I found this, man: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57286/make-function-payable-for-a-specific-erc20-token

Comment: Did you succeed on minting NFT on Polygon using WETH instead of MATIC? I have the same problem. I want to Mint using WETH in Polygon

Comment: No, it's best to MINT directly with MATIC. btw your answer should be a comment below my question :)

Comment: Thanks. Im sorry I can't directly comment below your question because It requires 50 reputation to comment.