# Must DAOs be paid with native asset? What flexibility is there in this structure?

Tags: tokens, dao, makerdao

This is more of a 'meta' question than anything else.

I was wondering if someone could create a DAO (crowdfund/ICO type contract), that redeems the tokens from the crowdsale in exchange for something other than ETH (in the case of $ETH) or BNB (in the case of Binance Chain).

Like, let's say for example, someone decides to hold a crowdsale for 'zeppelintokens'. But instead of accepting ETH in exchange (at a hypothetical conversion rate of 1 ETH / 200 zeppelintokens), someone wants to mandate that $MANA be given instead. Let's say they create a hypothetical exchange rate of 1MANA=20 zeppelintokens.

Is this possible to code into the smart contract itself? My initial assumption was "Of course", but I had a hard time conjuring any notable DAO examples that implement this type of crowdsale model apart from MakerDAO? I mention Maker because you can technically 'mint' $DAI with assets other than ETH (or 'WETH').

As the name of the project implies, 'MakerDAO' is, in essence, a 'DAO'.

**Note**: *You can disregard any mention/consideration of "price oracles" - the price would be pegged in this hypothetical scenario.*

#### Assuming the Answer is 'Yes'

Do you happen to know of any sample / example smart contract code or documentation floating around that outlines how to construct such a contract?

If not (or you don't feel like it), that's more than fine. Thank you in advance for taking the time (and patience) to answer this question!

Thanks in advance for taking the time to answer this question!

Comment: Please see this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/57290/620